# iOS Swift 3 select multiple rows in tableView initially at creation

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uikit

I want to select some rows when my tableView is loaded. Therefore I use this code inside my cellForRowAt:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "suggest", for: indexPath) as! groupViewControllerCell
    let item = self.feed!.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.title.text = item.name
    cell.setSelected(true, animated: true)
    return cell
}
```

The problem is, it selects all rows, but only for the blink of an eye. It quickly is deselected. My viewDidAppear has the following code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
tableView.allowsSelection = true
self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
self.loadAllGroups()
```

loadAllGroups gets all the data from the server and reloads the tableView afterwards.

```
func loadAllGroups()
{
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        self.updateGroupFeed(url, completion: { [unowned self] (feed) -> Void in
            self.feed = feed
        })
    }
}
```

updateGroupFeed looks like the following snippet:

```
func updateGroupFeed(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ feed: GroupFeed?) -> Void) {

    **headers for alamofire request**

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { [unowned self] response in
            guard let responseError = response.result.error else {
                let feed = GroupFeed(data: response.data!, sourceURL: url)
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ [unowned self] () -> Void in
                })
                completion(feed)
                return
            }
    }
}
```

**Now my question is**: How can I select the cells correctly? I use it to cache the users last selection.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are doing data fetching and table view configuration in `viewDidAppear()` instead of `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: no, i just put it together there. Could it be the problem?

Comment: You should move the tableview config to view did load. Please post your `loadAllGroups()` method so we can see how you are implementing the async.

Comment: i have added more code snippets now. and i have moved it to viewdidload, but that did not change the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the cell's selected state, which affects how the cell is rendered,  but you are not actually selecting the row, so as soon as the table refreshes, the selected state is lost.

You need to tell the tableview to select the cell using [`selectRowAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614875-selectrowatindexpath?language=objc).

I am not sure that you want to do this in `cellForRowAt`.  Selecting the cells in your completion handler might be a better idea.

Comment: thank you very much for explaining the difference! It works now.